# How to handle thread execution in coroutines?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a video playing application. I have implemented Vertical Viewpager2 with fragment. The fragment contains fullscreen exoplayer where I load the video and have a button to open the profile of the user who have posted the video. I make all the API calls in viewmodel as

```kotlin
viewmodelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
  ...  //making api call and updating the livedata
  ...
}
```

I am also using

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
   ...  //start caching the video
}
```

**The Problem is :**
When I scroll like 40 - 45+ items and launch any coroutine on `Dispatchers.IO`, the launch block is never executed hence the api calls are never made and app stops working.

**Debugging results :**
I tried to debug why the launch block is not executing with debug break points. In the **LimitingDispatcher** class, there is variable called **inFlightTasks** which is used to schedule the task if the parallelism limit is reached (which is 64 by default). So, my current task is added to ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable>. I waited for an hour but after scheduling the task it never resumed the task again. I checked the queue for the tasks and at the time of testing it had around 150-170 tasks but none of them resumed.

Any idea how to solve this problem.
Note : I cannot remove the caching of video(which is am using in onStart() of the fragment).

**EDIT**

1. I tried with `lifecycleScope.launch{ }` and `withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ }`, but I am still getting the same issue.
2. In viewModelScope

```kotlin
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
  val response = repository.call()
  when(repository){
     is Resource.Sucess -> livedata.postValue(response.data)
     is Resource.Error -> livedata.postValue(response.error)
  }
}
```

3. In lifecycleScope

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatcher.IO){
   try{
     startVideoCaching()
   }catch(e : Exception){
     e.printStackTrace()
   }
}
```

And both the functions in launch are purely suspend functions.

**Edit 2**

I am adding the screen shots of my functions and the `Dispatchers.IO`'s queue data.

1. Debug sscreenshot.
   [image]

The functions named in the debug screenshot.
In the `sendAnalytics` I am using `lifecycleScope` only
[image]

`cacheVideo()` is called from `onStart()`.
[image]

`markVideoView()` is called from `onResume()`
[image]

I tried with yield() but still no change in the behavior.
I am using all this methods in Fragment which is a part of ViewPager2 items.

Comment: We need to see the actual content of the coroutines to know what’s wrong. You usually should not be changing the dispatcher of `lifecycleScope.launch`. It is Android convention to leave it as Dispatchers.Main (the default) and wrap parts of the coroutine that need another dispatcher in something like `withContext` or `suspendCoroutine`.

Comment: What is the contents of launch blocks? are you calling pure suspend functions?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have updated the post. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @mightyWOZ I have updated the post. Please let me know if you need anything else

Comment: There's no point in specifying a dispatcher to call a suspend function. A correctly composed suspend function handles which dispatcher it runs on internally. Still not enough code to know what's wrong. What do the code in 2 and 3 have to do with each other? What do your suspend functions look like?

Comment: @Tenfour04 The code in 2 contains api calls like fetching user profile/video data. The code in 1 is to start caching videos for exoplayer even before start playing the video. I am using Dispatchers.IO to make api calls and the function used for caching the video is annotated as `@WorkerThread` by the exoplayer team, so I guess I need to use coroutine for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If it reached the parallelism limit, and the other ones are put in the queue, the only
logical reason they're not resuming and executing is that those previously called
are not suspending/returning to free up the threads for the queued ones to run.

What you should do is make your functions cancellable (cooperatively cancellable using
**isActive**) and those coroutines that are fired for the items that are no longer visible
on the screen (scrolled off the screen) should be cancelled, since there is no point of
calculating something not visible on the screen. By cancelling those coroutines you
should always have enough free threads to run those coroutines for the items currently visible on the screen.

In case you don't want to cancel coroutines fired for the items not currently on the screen, you can call `yield()` inside your functions to deliberately yield thread to other coroutines that run on the same thread pool.

Comment: I have used your suggestion but there is no change in the behavior. I have added screenshots of the methods for more insights.

Comment: Well you're calling the yield() at the end of the coroutine, when it's about to finish, so there's no point of doing that, To successfully use it, you need to divide your "processing" into a finite number of chunks, and after each chunk is completed you call yield() to yield the thread to other coroutines. The right approach though, would be as I said, to make your "processing" cooperatively cancellable and when the items get off the screen just cancel those coroutines.